# relationship between the proportion of a hash table (using open addressing) and expected search time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

next week I have Datastructure and algorithm exam and I am looking at some sample question but I cannot understand the following question:

Explain the relationship between the proportion of a hash table (using open addressing)
that is filled and the expected search time.

For me the search time is O(1) but I think it is not a good answer can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open addressing is a method of resolving collisions in hash tables.

Open adressing has three well known probing methods:

- Linear probing
- Quadratic probing
- Double hashing

Without loss of generality we can assume using any probing method.

Let's assume that you have hash function `h` and elements `E = [e1, e2, ..., en]`. Now let's assume that `h` is not too good so for each element in `E` we have `h(ex) = c` where `c` is some constant. Now if you add elements from `E` in order, and then ask for `n`-th element then access time will not be O(1) but O(n) for each call.

Answer (score 1):

Search time in the Open Addressing hasthable independents on number of keys (N).
So, in the notation big-O it is O(1).
However, it depends on "population ratio" in the hashtable, **a**:

Expected attempt numbers:

1. Successful search: (1/a) * Ln (1 / (1 - a));
2. Unsuccessful search: 1 / (1 - a);

Reference:

> Cormen & al, Introduction to Algorithms, 12.5-12.7